# Sort object by numeric value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following object:

```
{ key1: 5, key2: 3, key3: 1}
```

I now want to sort it by value so that I get:

```
{ key3: 1, key2: 2, key1: 5
```

I tried:

```
Object.keys(c).map(function (key) {return obj[key]});
```

But it didn't change the order.

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcuzr/295/

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` method might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the object to an array of arrays and then sort based on the second element in each subarray.

```js
var obj = { key1: 5, key2: 3, key3: 1};
var arr = [];

for (prop in obj) {
  arr.push([prop, obj[prop]]);
}

arr.sort(compare);

function compare(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
}

document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort the keys in an array, because objects have no order.

```js
var obj = { key1: 5, key2: 3, key3: 1 },
    keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    return obj[a]- obj[b];
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```